# Drag & drop to reorder them

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

[image]

I put my code here  http://jsfiddle.net/yPQZx/394/

**HTML**

```
<div id="example5">
<ul>
    <li>Start</li>
    <li>TOC</li>
     <li >section 1
        <ul>
            <li>chapter 1
                <ul>
                   <li>sub chapter1</li>
                    <li>sub chapter2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li >chapter 2<ul></ul></li>
            <li >chapter 3<ul></ul></li>
         </ul>
     </li>
     <li >section 2<ul></ul></li>
     <li >section 3<ul></ul></li>
     <li >section 4<ul></ul></li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#example5 ul").sortable({
    connectWith: "#example5 ul li",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
});

$("#example5 ul li ul ").sortable({
    connectWith: "#example5 ul li ul",
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
});
```

**CSS**

```
  ul { min-height:10px; }
  li { width: 150px; }
```

Could anyone help me to achieve this:

1. A subchapter can only be moved inside its chapter or another chapter, not directly under section
2. A chapter can only be moved inside its section or another section, not inside a chapter, not sibling of a section.
3. When a chapter is moved, all of its subchapters are moved with it.
4. A section can only be moved on a root place, not inside another section, chapter or subchapter!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd look at https://github.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable Although the developer is no longer looking after the project it is fully featured and should suit your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/yPQZx/398/)

Try this

```
$("#example5>ul>li>ul ").sortable({
                connectWith: "#example5>ul>li>ul",
                placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
});

$("#example5>ul>li>ul>li>ul ").sortable({
                connectWith: "#example5>ul>li>ul>li>ul",
                placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
});
$("#example5>ul>li").sortable({
                connectWith: "#example5>ul>li",
                placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
});
$("#example5>ul").sortable({
                connectWith: "#example5>ul",
                placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
});
```

Hope this helps, Thank you

Comment: why `section 1` can not move down under section 2,3,4,5

Comment: "A section can only be moved on a root place, not inside another section, chapter or subchapter!" you told not to

Comment: chapter1(sub chapter1 ,sub chapter2) can not move under chapter2,3 how about this?

Comment: "A chapter can only be moved inside its section or another section, not inside a chapter, not sibling of a section."

Comment: @BandOfBrothers, That's not possible, But am so happy with your words of appreciation itself, its like a vote for me, thank you.